# Retrieving modelsim signals into tcl

Tags: arrays, list, tcl, modelsim

How can I retrieve a Modelsim signal value in this form `x y` into tcl so I can process x and y individually?

Currently I have this line in tcl to trace a signal value

> when {/currentstate/comp_occupy} {set comp [exa
>   {/currentstate/comp_occupy}]}

This signal is a 2D array in Modelsim which is shown like `x y` in the widget.

This snippet should trace that variable

```
trace variable comp w grid_monitor

proc grid_monitor {name arrayindex op} {
    global comp flag_ttt cells
    if {$flag_ttt == 1} {
        puts $comp  
        puts [llength $comp]
        }

}
```

What I get out of this proc is like this `{x y}` but I have no idea how I can separate x and y. First I thought that's a list but `llength` returns 1!

Any idea how I can go about doing this? Or rather, how can I turn it into a proper list?

Thanks

Comment: What does `puts $comp` output from your proc?

Comment: for instance this `{1 3}` . it looks like a list but it seems to be all one element.

Comment: Well, if you have that in a list, like `[list {1 3}]` and use `puts [lindex [list {1 3}] 0]` you get `{1 3}`: that's 1 element. You need to split it. Try `puts [llength [split $comp]]`.

Comment: I added that to the proc and now it returns 2 but if I also add `puts [split $comp]` then the output is `\{1 3\}` ! Am I missing something?

Comment: Okay, that's the proof that `$comp` is not a list, but a string. I think it's best if you use something like `puts [string trim $comp "{}"]` and then `puts [llength [string trim $comp "{}"]]`. `string trim` will remove the characters `{` and `}` from the left and right of the string.

Comment: Great! It got rid of those `{}` . Now how can I actually turn it into a list so I can have direct access to each element?

Comment: Well, combining what we've discussed, you can put this line just above `puts $comp` to have a list: `set comp [split [string trim $comp "{}"]]`. If you want to get x = 3 and y = 1, you can use `lindex` or `lassign` (if you have Tcl 8.5 or later).

Comment: Oh right! Thanks a lot! I'm just new to all these tcl stuff thus such obvious questions! Later I might have some questions regarding sending back the same data structure from tcl to modelsim, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we established that the braces were literal braces, you can trim them out. Once done, you can then split to get a list:

```
proc grid_monitor {name arrayindex op} {
    global comp flag_ttt cells
    if {$flag_ttt == 1} {
        set new_comp [split [string trim $comp "{}"]]
        puts $new_comp  
        puts [llength $new_comp]
    }
}
```

`string trim` will trim from `$comp` the characters contained within the quotes, that is `{` and `}`. `split` will then split the string on space to give a list.

And if you want to assign `x` and `y` to the above, you can use `lindex` or `lassign` (if you have Tcl8.5 or later):

```
proc grid_monitor {name arrayindex op} {
    global comp flag_ttt cells
    if {$flag_ttt == 1} {
        set new_comp [split [string trim $comp "{}"]]
        puts $new_comp  
        puts [llength $new_comp]
        set x [lindex $new_comp 0]
        set y [lindex $new_comp 1]
        puts "x is $x and y is $y"
    }
}
```

Or...

```
set new_comp [split [string trim $comp "{}"]]
puts $new_comp  
puts [llength $new_comp]
lassign $new_comp x y
puts "x is $x and y is $y"
```

Answer (score 0):

In Tcl 8.5 the syntax to convert a string containing a valid list is to use the new expand operator:

```
set comp {*}$comp
```

It isn't clear if current versions of Modelsim have upgraded beyond 8.4 in which you need to do the same with eval:

```
eval set comp $comp
```

This uses the interpreter to do what it does best and avoids manually massaging the string.